# How can I add a long column at the end of a set of rows in Bootstrap?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, grid

This is likely a simple question, but it's causing me problems.

If I have three rows, how can I add an independent column that spans the height of all three rows to the right? E.g.:

```
[Row 1]                [Desired column]
  [col-xs-1]           ..............
  [col-xs-11]          ..............
[Row 2]                .............. 
  [col-xs-1]           ..............
  [col-xs-11]          ..............
[Row 3]                ..............
  [col-xs-1]           ..............
  [col-xs-11]          [end here]
```

How can I make the rows "end" so that I can add a column independent of them that spans the entire height to the right?

Comment: Can you give any screenshot or code..?

Comment: There is no enough room to set another column, because you are utilizing all 12 columns in rows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want something like this? You can use the class `.row-eq-height`, the CSS class is as follows.

```
.row-eq-height {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display:         flex;
}
```

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.row-eq-height {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row row-eq-height">
    <div class="col-xs-8">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-4">
          adfs
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4">
          asdf
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4">
          asdf
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-4">
          asdf
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4">
          asdf
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4">
          asdf
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4" style="background-color:red;">

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do this is html, in your table definition, use rowspan.

Eg-

```
<table>
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>first</th>
    <th rowspan="3">last</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>first row</td>

  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>second row</td>

  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>third row</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```